# stm32wb, nucleo-wb55, sensor, hardware

Tags: stm32, sensors, nucleo, hardware-design

I am using nucleo-wb55 development board with STM32WB55 processor. I want to connect sensors like IIS3DWB, STTS22H to this board. How can I go about connecting the modules of these sensors to nucleo-wb55?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect them via the I2C and SPI interfaces the board provides. Either built your own I2C/SPI or use the STM32 HAL provided functions.